# Ошибочно ли употребление тире в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

"По версии женщины, — она собралась окончательно вернуться в Россию и взять малыша с собой, но на него уже нацелилась местная мафия усыновителей".

"*По версии женщины*" лично я вижу как вводное слово, указывающее на источник сообщения, которое стоит отделить лишь запятой. Постановку тире прошу объяснить, если оно употреблено корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пунктуация точно ошибочна.

После вводных словосочетаний иногда ставят интонационное тире, но тогда тире просто **заменяет запятую**. Пример Розенталя:
*Он глубоко уважал своего друга, более того — восхищался им.*

Тире интонационное. Автор, конечно, имеет право (подчеркнуть важность следующей информации). Но оно здесь не особо удачно. Такое тире более удачно перед чем-то коротким, а не перед, по сути, всем предложением.

Но у такого подчёркивания появляется смысл, если до этого высказывалась другая, отличающаяся версия. Тогда здесь интонационный контраст, противопоставление.

Здесь создаётся некий интонационный контраст, так как источник информации фигурирует в этой же информации. При чём существительное и местоимение расположены именно по обе стороны тире. Источник информации настаивает (интонационно с помощью тире) на правильности своей версии, так как это решающим образом важно для него.
В других случаях такого не наблюдается:
*По версии следствия, она собралась окончательно вернуться в Россию.

По версии учёных, всё вокруг состоит из атомов.*

Можно выделить два варианта сопоставления информации:
1) яркое противопоставление:
*По одной версии, было так, а по другой — было совсем иначе.*
2) параллелизм, о котором говорит Sharon, при котором каждая версия подчёркивается, но между ними нет такого большого контраста:
*По одной версии — было так, а по другой — было вот так.*
Для второго варианта хорошо, если изначально очевидно, что версий будет несколько.

Comment: Полная версия звучит так: _По версии женщины, — она собралась окончательно вернуться в Россию и взять малыша с собой, но на него уже нацелилась местная мафия усыновителей. В итоге его отобрали и хотят продать бездетным итальянцам. Версия городских властей Бари: мать не справилась с жизненными трудностями, так и не сумела найти постоянной работы, поэтому ребенка изъяли в его интересах._ Применим ли Ваш последний абзац в данном случае, когда сначала была описана версия женщины, а потом другая?

Comment: Дальше — уже не важно, важно — до. Нашёл этот текст. Это почти начало. До этого других версий нет. Тире там заменяет запятую. В СМИ ошибки частенько встречаются. Розенталь говорил, что они "не несут свет грамотности миру". Просто решили сделать акцент на версии самой героини статьи. Это важный элемент текста.

Comment: Последний абзац сопоставим с правилом, когда тире заменяет союз "а": *Знание людьми законов не желательно — обязательно*. Имеем похожее, но с предложениями. Наоборот оно не работает: противопоставлять с помощью тире можно тому, что было ранее. Но подчеркнуть версию главной героини — это вполне логично.

Comment: Однако пунктуация все еще ошибочна, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Запятая там не нужна.